# Dropdown value does not change/set to default one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown created in angular js.

Refer below code :

```
<select name="artist" class="form-control selectpicker" ng-options="artists.Title for artists in artists track by artists.Id" ng-model="artist.Title">
    <option value="">Select Artist</option>
</select>
```

Here I am getting `artists` value from back end with REST API. And after getting into success callback I am calling another function i.e. `getSongs()` to get the selected Item Value.

```
var songIndex = $routeParams.index;
EditFactory.getArtists().then(getArtistsSuccess, getArtistsFailed);

function getArtistsSuccess(data) {
    if (data.data.d.results.length > 0) {
        $scope.artists = data.data.d.results;
    }
    ListFactory.getSongs().then(getSongsSuccess, getSongsFailed);
}

function getArtistsFailed(error) {
    console.log("empty artists from server -- addController");
}

function getSongsSuccess(data) {

    var currentSongObj = data.data.d.results.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.ID == songIndex;
    });

    $scope.listItems = data.data.d.results;
    $scope.artist = currentSongObj[0].Artist; // need to update this value in view

}

function getSongsFailed(error) {
    debugger;
}
```

Here `artist` value in not getting set in dropdown.

Refer below screenshot.

[image]

when I do alert on `$scope.artist.Title` I getting the right value. I am not able to find what I am doing wrong.

Please suggest me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code, maybe typo, anyways, you should write `select` as:

```
<select name="artist" class="form-control selectpicker" 
      ng-options="artist as artist.Title for artist in artists  track by artist.Id" 
      ng-model="selectedArtist">
    <option value="">Select Artist</option>
</select>
```

Where `selectedArtist`

```
$scope.selectedArtist = {
    Id:2
};
```

<kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyae5tf2/)</kbd>